# Is there another equal way to write the code shown below? Option Strict does not allow this late binding

Tags: vb.net

```
{With CurrentFont
   NewFontStyle = -((Not .Underline) * FontStyle.Underline)
   NewFontStyle += -(.Bold * FontStyle.Bold)
   NewFontStyle += -(.Italic * FontStyle.Italic)
End With}
```

I just do not understand how this code work. If someone could just explain the use of minus and asterisk signs  I can probably figure the rest out.

Comment: Is this the same result? `NewFontStyle += -(.Bold * FontStyle.Bold)` == `NewFontStyle -= (.Bold * FontStyle.Bold)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeremy. Sorry but still it is does not work. But thanks anyway. I have found a way to rewrite it and will post it in a couple of days after I return home. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be using mathematical operations where what's actually desired are logical and bitwise operations. `FontStyle` is an `Enum` with the `Flags` attribute applied, indicating that multiple values can be combined. What that code appears to be doing is creating a `FontSyle` value with the same `Bold` and `Italic` values and the opposite `Underline` value of `CurrentFont`. That can be done far more succinctly using proper code:

```vb
NewFontStyle = CurrentFont.Style Xor FontSyle.Underline
```

If you want to make absolutely sure that `Strikethrough` is not set then you can do this:

```vb
NewFontStyle = CurrentFont.Style Xor FontSyle.Underline And Not FontStyle.Strikethrough
```

When performing bitwise operations, `Or` sets a bit, `And Not` resets a bit and `Xor` toggles a bit, so `Or` effectively adds a style, `And Not` removes a style and `Xor` toggles a style.

Depending on how this code is used, you may be able to improve more of the code by doing it properly. This code will effective toogle the `Underline` style of `CurrentFont` while leaving other styles as they are:

```vb
CurrentFont = New Font(CurrentFont, CurrentFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Underline)
```

Comment: Thanks jm, I appreciate the insight.  I will give them a try and let you now in a next week when I return home how things work out, Once again, I really appreciate your response.